# Tell .NET WebApi where Client-Routing starts

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-web-api, routes, client-server

My app contains 2 participial apps. A asp.net-WebApi and an angular2-clientsite-app.

I made 2 websites for the 2 apps on my IIS-Server and I have a routing problem.

The URL's to the 2 websites are:

WebApi: http://testurl.com/api/

Angular2: http://testurl.com/ui/

Now on my anuglar2 application I implemented a typical angular-routing which allows me to visit for example this link:
http://testurl.com/ui/search/result/562335

If I navigate to the main site, I can easily click to this link, but if an foreign user copies that link and shares it with his friends and they start visiting my site by clicking on that link, the IIS-Servers tells them, the link is broken...

How can I edit the web.config file to allow them visiting the link directly?

Thank you in advanced for a helping answer!

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty easy solution for my issue.

In your routing file "app.routing.ts" you can just add the parameter useHash: true to the ExtraOptions of your routing That's because the IIS needs the segment delimiter '#' to recognize until he got to serve a website. After the # IIS knows, the rest of the URL belongs to the client-app. Now it looks like this (Pay attention to the last line of code):

```
   export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: Search },
  { path: 'login', component: Login },
  { path: 'index.html', component: Search },
  { path: 'searchRooms', component: Search },
  { path: 'searchRooms/inquire', component: Search },
  { path: 'searchRooms/reserve', component: Search },
  { path: 'searchRooms/authCatcher', component: Search },
  { path: 'searchRooms/redirect', component: Search },
  { path: 'searchRooms/scheduler', component: Search },
  { path: 'searchRooms/scheduler/:roomId', component: Search },
  { path: 'inquire', component: Inquire },
  { path: 'register', component: Reserve },
  { path: '**', component: NotFound }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: true});
```

now angular changes all routes automatically: localhost:8080/search becomes localhost:8080/#/search so IIS exactly knows the route after the segment delimiter '#' is not ment for him and serves it to the client.

There are also 2 other possibilities to solve this problem:

1. Create a url-rewriteRule into the web.config file. The problem here is, your browser will only be able to serve exactly 1 site from outside: the first angular-site. If you want to navigate from outside to a specific site of angular, this will not be possible.
2. Change your error-page 404 in IIS (a little hackish): In this solution you would tell your IIS his error page is the angular application. If he cannot serve the link provided to him, he just calls angular as error-page and angular will receive the url and can route to the right site.

Notwithstanding my solution has proven to be the best